# NameError: name 'e' is not defined, how to count correct

Tags: python, list, count

1. I splited the sentence.
2. I want to count the the character "e" in my variable "s" as a second step.

I have tried `s_list.count(e)` , `s_list.count("e")` and many others

Code:

```
s = "Ich lerne Python"

s_list = s.split() #Spaltung vom String
s_list.sort() #Sortierung

print(s_list)


s_list.count(e)
print(s_list)

['Ich', 'Python', 'lerne']
```

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
NameError                                 Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-72-29d14ddb1793> in <module>()
      3 s_list.sort() #Sortierung
      4 print(s_list)
----> 5 s_list.count(e)
      6 print(s_list)

NameError: name 'e' is not defined
```

Comment: if you have list with words then you will have to count `"e"` in every word separatelly and later sum all values. You will need `for`-loop for this. OR count `"e"` before you split it.

Answer (score 1):

Why not simply `s.count("e")`. You can use the count method directly on a string. The problem you have, but you apparently already tried it differently, as you stated in your question, is, that `e` is a variable and you want to search for`"e"`, the letter "e".

After you apply the split method however you have a list of strings in which you search for the letter "e". You can't find any, since your list does not have an entry of "e", but looks the following: `['Ich', 'lerne', 'Python']`. Split does not split after every letter, but at whitespaces.

If you want to go over the splited string you can do something like:

```
count_e = 0
for word in s_list:
    count_e = count_e + word.count("e")
```

or in list comprehension:

```
count_e = sum([word.count("e") for word in s_list])
```

Answer (score 1):

There are multiple ways of approaching the task for counting specific characters in a string, below are 2 approaches you can play with, I would recommend approach 2 as using count function as it is simpler and also does away with a loop.

**Approach 1 - For loop**

```
# initializing string  
test_str = "Ich lerne Python"

# counting e  
count = 0

for i in test_str: 
    if i == 'e': 
        count = count + 1
```

**Approach 2 - Count**

```
# count() 

# initializing string  
test_str = "Ich lerne Python"

# using count() to get count  
# counting e  
counter = test_str.count('e') 

# printing result  
print ("Count of e in Ich lerne Python is : " +  str(counter))
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have list with strings then you have to count `"e"` for every string separatelly and sum values.

```
s_list = ['Ich', 'Python', 'lerne']

result = 0

for word in s_list:
    result = result + word.count("e")

print(result)
```

The same with list comprehension

```
s_list = ['Ich', 'Python', 'lerne']

result = sum(word.count("e") for word in s_list)

print(result)
```

---

BTW: You could count `"e"` before you split it

```
s = "Ich lerne Python"

result = s.count("e")

print(result)
```